# How is my form being submitted when one of the required date fields is empty?

Tags: php, html, forms, required

Most of the forms come through with the DOB entered. A few (out of hundreds) get through with no DOB listed.

The HTML form starts with:

```
<form id="registration-form" class="forms reg-form-layout" method="POST">
```

and the field has Required (relevant bits):

```
<div class="field-group-h-2">
  <label class="form-label field-label" id="reg-drj-dob-l" for="reg-drj-dob-f">Date of birth*</label>
  <input class="form-control form-field" id="reg-drj-dob-f" type="date" name="regDateOfBirth" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["regDateOfBirth"])) echo $_POST["regDateOfBirth"]; ?>" required="required" 
</div>
<div class="form-button-container">
  <button class="btn btn-primary form-button" id="reg-new-submit" type="submit" value="submit" form="registration-form" name="regSubmit">Submit</button>
</div> 
<p class="paragraph form-result"><?php echo $_SESSION["regResult"];?></p>
<p class="paragraph form-errors"><?php echo $_SESSION["regErrors"];?></p>
```

The PHP also has validation checks (relevant bits):

```
    $regDateOfBirth = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
      if (empty($_POST["regDateOfBirth"]))
      {
        $regDateOfBirthErr = "Date of birth (required) ";
      } 
      else 
      {
        $tempDateOfBirth = date_create($_POST["regDateOfBirth"]); $regDateOfBirth = date_format($tempDateOfBirth, 'd-m-Y');
      }
    
      $anyDateErr = $regDateOfBirthErr;
        
      if (!$anyDateErr)
      {
        post the form data to a text file on the server and send it in an email
      }
      else 
      {
        $_SESSION["regErrors"] = "There is an error with your: $anyDateErr "; 
      }
```

(please forgive any syntax errors made from copying and pasting bits from the main, very long file)

When testing, I cannot submit the form without putting a date in that field.

Neither the email with the form on it, nor the text file on the server that I send the field values to, have the DOB in them for this small portion of users.

How can it be that a small number of people are able to submit with an empty field?

Could it be a browser thing?

Or maybe by setting a date field to "" initially I'm causing potential issues?

**Update:**

I amended the Required attribute. Thanks

I found a form that didn't have a DOB on it, checked the time it was submitted and checked the error logs on the server.  That submission seems to have generated the following error:

> PHP Warning:  date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given in /assets/php/form-reg.php on line 97

I changed the PHP validation to:

```
if (empty($_POST["regDateOfBirth"])){$regDateOfBirthErr = "Date of birth (required) ";
}   
else
{
$tempDateOfBirth = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST["regDateOfBirth"]); 
  if ($tempDateOfBirth == FALSE){$regDateOfBirthErr = "Date of birth 
  format incorrect";
  }
  else
  {
    $regDateOfBirth = $tempDateOfBirth->format('d-m-Y');
  }
}
```

Thanks

I've got a different error to deal with now but I'll need a new post for that

Comment: required="required" remove this from input field and check again.

Comment: whitespace counts as content. It is also trivial for anyone to submit form data manually . the `required` attribute is only set on the **sender** not by the **receiver**.

Comment: "Could it be a browser thing?" - Yes, it is. PHP has no physical means to control the data it _receives_. It's also worth noting that browsers are not the only tool to generate HTTP requests.

Comment: @DelowarHossen `required="required"` is perfectly valid XHTML if OP is using that. However for standard HTML the attribute alone is enough so simply have `<input ... required>`

Comment: You may find it very useful to turn on error reporting, I see some! Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Martin Woops wong canned message

Comment: Wow, y'all are fast. I've added an update to the post. I can't test if changing the Require attribute will make any difference until I leave it for a period of time and see if any other omission forms get through.

Comment: Error reporting does not show any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (empty($_POST["regDateOfBirth"]))` this line only check if it is empty or not. If i happen to send wrong date then this condition will satisfy unintentionally (example '154-134-41').

`date_create($_POST["regDateOfBirth"]);` this function will return false if your date format is incorrect.

`date_format($tempDateOfBirth, 'd-m-Y')` this will throw exception same as you mentioned if you pass boolean to it.

changing the `required` attribute on html has nothing to do with this issue.

your server should not assume that it will get right data because you have safe guards on your html. Please validate your data on server properly, irrespective of checks on html/js.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I have to use something other than 'is empty' for date fields and also check the date format in case it hasn't been entered using the calendar popup, which I can't assume will always be used...?

Comment: yes, ```date_create``` return false if a valid date format is not passed to it. you can check that.